# Timestamp Spring conversion

Tags: java, spring, timestamp

I'm trying to work with timestamp. I've defined in the jsp a hidden var from a bean.

```
<form:input type="hidden" path="timeStamp" />

private Timestamp timeStamp;

public final Timestamp getTimeStamp() {
return (timeStamp == null)
? null : (Timestamp) timeStamp.clone();
}

public final void setTimeStamp(Timestamp timeStamp) {
this.timeStamp = (timeStamp == null)
? null : (Timestamp) timeStamp.clone();
}
```

The Timestamp is generated in the insert operation, and I need it for the delete op. My problem is, that in the controller, once I'm trying to delete the record recently inserted, this timeStamp is null (but it isn't null in the jsp)

```
public final void doActionDelete(DumyBean bean, Errors errors, ActionRequest actionrequest...)
```

bean.timeStamp is equal to null?? I'm sure that the timestamp is in the jsp, so I guess the problem is about data conversion.

(Edited:) I think that the problem is the initBinder method, where I'm doing something like this...

```
@InitBinder
public final void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Is it possible that, the date is parsed to be shown in the JSP with the "dd/MM/yyyy" format, and after that spring doesn't know how to transform it again into timeStamp??

In the doAction method, the errors var show this error, that seems the problem is where I said, but I've no idea how to fix it.

```
"Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property 'timeStamp'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
[java.sql.Timestamp] for property 'timeStamp': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor] 
returned inappropriate value of type [java.util.Date]
```

Comment: Please describe your question in more detail, to get quick and better answer

Comment: No problem. What do you need to know..?

Comment: initbinder should have taken effect both ways - if it converted your timestamp to dd/MM/yyyy when presenting on screen, it should have been able to convert it back also. See if there is some more information printed by Spring if you can run with DEBUG mode. One more thing to try could be to use a java.util.Date

Comment: It should be, but actually it doesn't. I've edited my question to show an error in the controller doAction method: "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is written in the exception:

> PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor] 
>   returned inappropriate value of type [java.util.Date]

This mean the `CustonDateEditor` retuns a `java.util.Date` but you need a `Timestamp`.

Therefore you can do two things:

- write your own PropertyEditor and register it (see http://adfinmunich.blogspot.de/2011/04/how-to-write-sqltimestamppropertyeditor.html), or
- use `Date` instead of `Timestamp`

Comment: Your solution seems to be fine. I'm just having some problems with the timestamp format to parse it. Anyway, thanks a lot!